# execute git commands through bash script in other directory

Tags: linux, git, bash

is there a way to execute git commands in a bash script, add the changed files, commit it with a comment then push them to the server where the bash file isn't in the directory of the repository?

this is what I have, and everything works except the commit,

```
cd /home/repos
git add file.txt

echo "comment: "
read input_varible

git commit -m '$input_varible'
git push origin master
```

when the commit line executes I get this error,

```
error: bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

but when i do everything in the terminal it works fine.

and yes i have tried to reset the indexes by using this command but it doesnt work

```
    rm -f .git/index
    git reset
```

I am working on a linux if that helps

Comment: Note that the single quotes around `'$input_varible'` in the `commit` mean that a constant string is used, not what the user typed.  Use double quotes!

Comment: wow thank you so much - it was such a simple mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. I am doing it by adding an alias to the script in my `~/.bash_profile` file.

Since you're adding an alias, do not forget to reload your terminal. Oh yeah, and you don't need all of the `cd /path/to/directory` stuff since you need to launch your command inside the repository directory.